# Routing problem shows this Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway

Tags: linux, ip, routing, iproute

I am trying to route some traffic over a VPN (to certain IPs) and other via my normal connection. To do this I am trying to add a static route to make traffic to some IPs bypass the VPN tunnel.

Very strangely it seems to work for some IPs and not for others giving the ***Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.***

So This works:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ip r add 193.27.14.179/32 via 127.31.1.1 dev eth0

root@ubuntu:~# ip r
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 49.12.189.197 metric 100 
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 49.12.189.197 metric 100 
193.27.14.179 via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0
```

This doesn't work:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ip r add 168.119.56.29/32 via 127.31.1.1 dev eth0
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

So what is going on.. I would appreciate any advises or comments!

```
root@ubuntu:~# route -n
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
193.27.14.179   172.31.1.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0


root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
root@ubuntu:~# ip r show table local
local 49.12.189.197 dev eth0 proto kernel scope host src 49.12.189.197 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
root@ubuntu:~# ip r show table main
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 49.12.189.197 metric 100 
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 49.12.189.197 metric 100 
193.27.14.179 via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 
root@ubuntu:~# ip r show table default
Error: ipv4: FIB table does not exist.
Dump terminated


root@ubuntu:~# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: Is the dest 127.31.1.1 a typo and should be 172.31.1.1? 127.31.1.1 is a loopback address (the entire 127.0.0.0/8 is loopback for ipv4, not only 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Just tried to switch eth0->lo in your command. It works (but makes no sense of course)